# Installing Qt Creator on Debian

Tags: debian, software-installation, qtcreator

I'm following this guide http://exploringbeaglebone.com/chapter11/ and I am stuck at part

> Click on the “Qt Versions” tab and click on “Add…” and browse to
>   /usr/bin/ where you should see the qmake and qmake-qt4 entries. Click
>   on qmake and then click Open. You should then see that a manual Qt
>   version has appeared as in Figure 2 below.

in step 3.

I have not these two files, I installed qmake with sudo apt-get install qmake and followed all these steps from the start, but no files, what can be wrong?

Comment: Since you didn't specify it explicitely, is there a reason not to use the version in the offical repo?

Comment: There's a `qtcreator` package in Debian. If you want one which is more recent than that in your release, you're probably out of luck, because I bet it is tied to the Qt/KDE libraries on your system.